# If($true) in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've come across an `If($True)` statement in a script I'm working on, but I haven't been able to really tell what exactly that's doing. It seems that the script proceeds into the next block regardless, and I haven't found anything that'd cause it to NOT execute the next section (a Try/Catch statement).

Of course, I understand what it would mean if it were `If($var -eq $true)`, but without the variable there for it to check I just don't understand what this is doing

Edit: Example

```
If($True){
   Try {Write-Host "Hello World"}
   Catch {"oops"}
   }
```

vs

```
If($var -eq $True){
   Try {Write-Host "Hello World"}
   Catch {"oops"}
   }
```

Comment: please show a [mcve]. `if ($true)` and `if ($var -eq $true)` are very different due to the casting rule in comparison operartors

Comment: Afaik, `If($True) { <expression> }` is indeed bogus, you might as well just excute the `<expession>`. Maybe it is used for a ([AST](https://powershell.one/powershell-internals/parsing-and-tokenization/abstract-syntax-tree)) template.

Comment: Perhaps it got left in there as a remnant of debugging, or for ease of adding another option.

Comment: this is not a [mcve]. No one knows what `$var` is, what type and value it contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `If($True)` statement isn't strictly necessary as it will always evaluate to `True` and proceed to execute the script block. I can see why this is confusing, because it's semantically superfluous.

Basically, if the value inside the `()` evaluates to anything other than `$false`, `0`, `$null`, or `""`(an empty string), it will execute the script block.

Why it's written that way is probably only known to the author. If I had to guess, perhaps it is to keep the style of the code similar to other code around it. I certainly wouldn't have bothered writing it as anything other than a simple `Write-Host "Hello World"` unless there was some sort of style guide mandating that format, or other reason to wrap everything in `if`s and try/catch blocks.